# Visio Web Access web part

Tags: visio

We are using 'Visio web Access' web part for rendering a Visio web drawing. We also have mashup scripts to view the shape data.

Just want to know if using Visio Web Access web part and mashup scripts will need any ECAL?

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2010 Visio web access is a part of Enterprise version. You have to get ECAL.

http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-web-parts-by-license-type

In SharePoint 2013 Visio Web Access Web Part is still the part of the [Visio Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee663485(v=office.15).aspx), so you have to get ECAL too.

http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/